# Incrementing a value every day

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I will try to be as clear as possible in my explanation.
So here I have a script on my site that allows sms to be sent free of charge, so that people do not abuse this "free", I would like to set up a general daily sms credit quotation.

My question is: Is it possible to limit the execution of a script (50 times for example) based on the time utc for example from 00h01 to 23h59. ?

thank you

Comment: You can save how many times a script is executed with SQL, if it has been run more than 50 times, just don't let them send a message. Client based, you can't restrict a person a 100%, as someone can always change their ip or delete their cookies.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a database (MySQL, PostgreSQL...) to count uses and block the access once the threshold is reached.

Comment: Yes this is what i intend to do but how do I increment the daytime +50 automatically in my MYSQL database?

Comment: Do we assume you have to login before you can send SMS, and therefore you mean 50 texts per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found with

```
CURDATE()+0
```

And an increment of +1 to a given maximum value (eg 30 sms).